# Prove that $\cos(x)$ doesn't have a limit as $x$ approaches infinity.

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been working on this one for quite a long time now.

I have to prove that $\cos(x)$ has no limit as $x$ approaches infinity.
Let $\epsilon>o$ and M be any number greater than 0, so that for any x>M:$$|\cos(x)-L| < \epsilon$$
I'm not sure how am I to show that for a specific $L$(anywhere in between $-1$ to $1$) I would choose, I could find ε that would contradict $$|\cos(x)-L| < \epsilon$$
For example, if I choose $\epsilon =1/2$ and $L=1/4$ then for $\cos(x)=1$ the expression above is wrong ,thus $1/4$ isn't the limit, but this happens with any L I chose.
Is giving one example of an arbitrarily chosen L enough?
I cannot give 100 examples, now cannot I?

(tia)

Comment: Regardless of any formal proof, you can tell that the function will oscillate forever, so, that would amount to an intuitionist's proof.

Comment: This is not entirely wrong. You can argue that you can pick a sequence of points in the real line such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos a_n=1$$ while for another sequence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos b_n=0$$ In fact, as long as $\ell\in[-1,1]$, we can find a sequence of points for which $\cos x_n\to\ell$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show that there is no such $L$, you can show that $\cos x$ will always assume points more than $\epsilon$ apart for some $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\epsilon <1$. $\cos 2n\pi = 1$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$, and $\cos\left((2n + 1)\pi\right) = -1$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$, so that no matter what $N$ you choose, you can always find $x = 2n\pi,x' = (2n + 1)\pi > N$ such that $\left|\cos x - \cos x'\right| = 2 > \epsilon$.

**Edit (for completeness):** You can use the triangle inequality to show that the above implies so such $L$ can work. Do you see it?

> ! This implies that no $L$ satisfies $\left|\cos x - L\,\right| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ whenever $x > M_{\epsilon}$ (some $M_{\epsilon}\in\Bbb{R}$) because if it did, we would have
>   $$
> \left|\cos 2n\pi - L\,\right| = \left| 1 - L\,\right| < 1/4
> $$
>   for $2n\pi > M_{1/4}$,
>   $$
> \left|\cos (2n + 1)\pi - L\,\right| = \left|-1 - L\,\right| = \left| 1 + L\,\right| < 1/4
> $$
>   for $(2n+1)\pi > M_{1/4}$, so
>   $$
> 2 = \left|1 - L + 1 + L\,\right| \leq \left| 1 - L\,\right| + \left| 1 + L\,\right|< 2\cdot \left(1/4\right) < 1/2,
> $$
>   which is absurd.

Comment: Hm. Spoiler >! not working... anyone have any idea why?

Comment: To me this answer seems overly complicated.

Comment: @MrOperator certainly there are more elegant ways ($\cos n\pi = (-1)^n$), but I feel like this assumes very little: you only need to know that cosine is periodic and assumes $1$ and $-1$ (the argument doesn't apply limit theorems). The triangle inequality part can be adapted for any nonconstant periodic function, so it's pretty general as well. I wouldn't say it's overly complicated, just precise.

Comment: Great explanation with easy example.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more general way. Pick an L between -1 and 1. And an $\epsilon < 1$. Note that the cosine function bijective on a period. Therefore you can find an $x$ such that 
$|cos(x) - L| >\epsilon. $
Now note that the same holds for $|cos(x+n2\pi) - L|$ with $n$ a natural number.

Comment: Could I just pick an L?

Comment: Indeed in fact you could choose any L. The point of the argument is that on period you can find an $x$ that such that $\cos(x)$ is not close to $\cos(L)$.

But an $L$ not in -1 to 1 can be excluded since $\cos(x)$ lies between -1 and 1 by the sandwich theorem.

Comment: I'm aware of the sandwich theorem but cannot quite get your point. Could you come again please?

Comment: You can use this argument to show that the limit is not $L$ for any $L$ in $\mathbb{R}$. So it is a perfectly valid proof. However conceptually if you would think the cosine function would have a limit, I want to point out that the limit can't be anything outside $[-1,1]$ since the function does not take on values there. This you can prove precisely with the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the limit is L, and show that it can't be. Hint: $\cos \pi n = (-1)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Observe that $\cos (x)$ is a [Periodic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) provided $f(x)=\cos x$ is not a constant as Stahl suggests.

Comment: Down voter care to explain?

Comment: Because what you had previously written was wrong. (it wasn't me though).

Comment: What about now?

Comment: It wasn't me, but perhaps the downvoter was suggesting that certain periodic functions do have such limits? E.g. $f(x) = 1$

Comment: @Stahl: $f(x)=1$.Is that a periodic function?

Comment: @Inceptio $f(x + k) = f(x)$ for any $k$, so it's periodic with any period. (Unless you have the convention that a periodic function must be nonconstant, in which case it isn't :))

Comment: @Stahl Yeah! Every constant function $f(x)=c$ has a limit $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if such limit, say $L$, exists, then any sequence of the form $a_n:=\cos(x_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N},\ x_n \in dom( \cos x)$ satisfies 
$$a_n \longrightarrow L.$$
Now, think if this is true for all sequences in the mentioned form.

Comment: I would be more than happy to ponder about your advice, although I haven't acquired enough knowledge about number sets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon\leq1$, and for arbitrary $N>0$, we pick  $n$ such that $x=2\pi$ $n>N$ for some $n$; now, $\cos(x)= 1$, but $\cos(x+\pi)= -1$ and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Your answer is nearly equivalent to Stahl's.